# Woocommerce API rest client retrieve products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using a Woocommerce REST client API to get products from a Wordpress website. However, when I execute this command:

```
this->client->products->get();
```

to get all products, I only have 10 products returned. What might be the problem?

Comment: It sounds like you need to provide a `numberposts` or `posts_per_page` parameter with your request.

Comment: how i could do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Nothing to do with the rest client itself.
It is wordpress configuration.
Just got to
settings -> Reading -> and change "Blog pages show at most" or "Syndication feeds show the most recent" to (50) or as you like

Hope it is helping .

Comment: It solves the problem but not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `Blog pages show at most` property is not the solution to this problem. By doing that you're changing behaviour of other pages on your site too. Use following code instead:

```
$this->client->products->get(null, array('filter[limit]' => -1));
```

use `-1` to get all the products or just use any number to limit it upto that number.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all the products use the limit filter,

To get the 50 products ----  filter[limit]=50

To get all the products ---  filter[limit]=-1

http://example.com/wc-api/v3/products?filter[limit]=50&oauth_consumer_key=ck_050f0a06050e2789b2c61d6bd66d2c97d3780580&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1448179257&oauth_nonce=Ac52xk&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=eBm5/3CP6kw1K8F033wHnVpAKiw=

No need to change the code etc. only use the limit filter.